# How to set up the enviroment for SilverStripe module testing in Gitlab-CI

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, silverstripe

I'm trying to setup GitLab-CI for internal testing of my SilverStripe sites at work. For the individual sites this setup is fine, sites are cloned and tests run and all is okay. But I have a couple of modules shared across these sites that I would like to test & develop independently.

When it comes to running the build in GitLab-CI, obviously a test environment needs to be set up. Currently these modules get developed in their own 'dummy' site environments, and I use git to control each module folder. So, when builds are run in GitLab-CI, it means that cms and framework get installed to the same dir, then `sake dev/build flush=all` is run.

In the case of my modules, the is no `_config.php` that does anthing like load `conf/configurefromenv`, and looking at other modules on github, configs like this don't seem to be included in the repos?

So what do i need to do to get this working? Am I missing something here?

**Also:** After asking in IRC, some people have drawn to my attention the behat & travis extensions, I take it a similar extension would have to be made to support gitlab? What exactly do these modules do? (I am going to dive into the code but if someone could give me an overview that would be great!)

Comment: so, the problem is that the modules are not recognized by SilverStripe? But I don't understand how that would be possible, because then they would also not be recognized in your dummy environment.

Comment: No the modules are fine when used on SS sites. Its not so much SilverStripe, but the fact that I was unsure how to set up a test environment in the build steps on GitLab-CI. I've figured it out now though, I made my own support module: https://github.com/dangerdan/silverstripe-gitlab-ci-support

Comment: ah I see. glad you got it working. could you post your solution as answer to this question and mark it as resolved please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by writing my own build script, see:

http://github.com/dangerdan/silverstripe-gitlab-ci-support